# Setting reference to a dynamically created Component

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm inheriting from a razor component (from antdesign) and trying to set a reference to the new component dynamically, I looked at the .razor.g.cs but it seems like it's not working the way I copied it.

Input Wrapper component :

```
@inherits Input<string>

@RenderBase()

@code {
    private Input<string> _ref;
    RenderFragment RenderBase() => builder =>
        {   
            var callback = EventCallback.Factory.Create<FocusEventArgs>(this, arg =>
            {
             //Do something
            });
            builder.OpenComponent(0, typeof(Input<string>));
            builder.AddAttribute(1, "OnFocus", callback);
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "AllowClear", true);
            builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(3, (__value) => {
             _ref = (Input<string>)__value;
            });
            builder.CloseComponent();   
};
}
```

I would like being able to use the AddComponentReferenceCapture to avoid repeating a reference each time I want to use the InputWrapper component, is that possible?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not just using Razor syntax for this?

Comment: To avoid having to repeat the declaration of a reference in my component file each time I want to use the InputWrapper, If I have 5-6 InputWrapper in a component it can become quite messy

Comment: I don't see how doing it in code makes that any easier though - if your wrapper just used markup like `<Input @ref=@_ref AllowClear="true" OnFocus=@FocusHandler ...etc/>` , why would that mean you have to repeat anything?

Comment: If I use <InputWrapper @ref="_ref" /> then I would need to declare that _ref each time I invoke InputWrapper, or am I mistaken? If I do it in code I only do it in the InputWrapper.razor

Comment: I'm not suggesting that though - I'll post an answer to make it clearer

Comment: Actually, the more I think about this, the less sense it makes - You want a wrapper to prevent writing code to get the component reference every time, so presumably that means the code that uses InputWrapper needs access to the reference, so how is that happening in your design?
 - Your `_ref` variable is private and the code containing the instance of InputWrapper has no way to access it without a component reference to the instance of InputWrapper
What are you trying to achieve with this wrapper?

Comment: So basically, in the callback I set the _ref to a state container holding the element reference on each focus, and another component ( which is a keyboard) listen to see if there is a focus on an element reference and if the keyboard is shown, it changes the value of this elementreference hold in the state container)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "code" based approach is basically the same as this, but more difficult.
There may be other attributes, such as a value to bind to, but you don't show them in your question.

```html
@inherits Input<string>

<Input @ref=@_ref OnFocus=@FocusHandler AllowClear="true"/>

@code {
  private Input<string> _ref;
  
  Task FocusHandler(FocusEventArgs args)
  {
  // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok yes I see what you meant, the reason I wanted to do it programmatically was to avoid repeating all the parameters like you did

Comment: avoid how? you still had to write code for them?

Comment: Not really since the implementation is already done in Input<string>, you just inherits it

Comment: I am not following - your question has code that just does the same as the markup in this answer - they are not any different, except one is easier than the other. I have not repeated anything you didn't. I think what you are trying to do is extend their Input so that you can retrieve a component reference and pass that to a service when the component is focussed. Everything else you want to behave just like their Input component. Correct?